# Port forwarding with two routers?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port

Can someone walk me through port forwarding with two routers, I will post screenshots as needed. I've tried many tutorials online and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Please add router model also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have one router connected to internet and the other to the first one: the easiest will be putting the second one in DMZ of the first one. That will make the second be virtually connected to the internet. Then you can configure port forwarding in the second router as usual.